# Configurable roles for authorization in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, rbac, ng-show

I am developing an app where the roles are not strictly defined. The roles are imported from a service.

I am using AngularJS with UI Router.

I have my states defined in the app, but is there an easy way to map states or UI components (divs, buttons, etc) to roles on the fly?

I am thinking about having a UI which would list all my states and all my roles, and an admin can define the access to each state based on role, and then when the actual user logs in, they are only able to see the relevant sections they have been allowed to see, probably by setting ng-show directive.

If there is a simpler solution, help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying that you have an application with a fixed set of states, but a dynamic set of roles (which control access to the fixed set of states). Is that correct?

If so, then a high-level way I would approach this would be to create a directive that you can attributes HTML buttons or links with (something like `if-permission="some-permission"`), and then that directive could determine whether or not the user has a given permission by checking the JSON data you've retrieved from your server.

I created a Gist a while back for a somewhat-similar question that you might find useful? Maybe, maybe not. Either way, here it is:
https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/90343c06467e9bcb8d27